# PostgreSQL how to copy a group of entries whilst changing some values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table with topological data, fields are x,y,z,gradient,timestamp,user

now arises the problem to copy data from one layer to the other...
means copy all data from say (10,20,30) to (1200,1900,30) to the same x,y but z+1, and changing the timestamp and user to the one of the actual submitter.

i did this programmaticly (php frontend) but its extremely slow...
so i wondered if there was a clever way doing this in SQL directly?

Comment: Which fields are `10, 20, 30`?

Comment: @Quassnoi '(10,20,30) to (1200,1900,30) to the same x,y but z+1': looks like they are x, y and z

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable (layer1, layer2, layer3, x, y, x, gradient, timestamp, user)
SELECT  1200, 1900, 30, x, y, z + 1, gradient, NOW(), $current_user
FROM    mytable
WHERE   (layer1, layer2, layer3) = (10, 20, 30)
```

Comment: -1 because the question does not mention fields called `layerN` and because $current_user is not 'SQL directly'

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of guesswork about your intent:

```
insert into mytable(x, y, z, gradient, "timestamp", "user")
select x, y, z+1, gradient, localtimestamp, current_user
from mytable
where z=30 and x>=10 and x<=1200 and y>=20 and y<=1900;
```

replace `localtimestamp` and `current_user` with your hardcoded values if necessary (eg 'pipo')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is about SQL in general and not Postgres specifically, it's probably something like this. I use SQL Server and Sybase usually, but I imagine Postgres is similar.

```
INSERT INTO
   SomeTable (x,y,z,...)
SELECT
   x, y, z+1, ...
FROM
   SomeTable
WHERE
   ...
```

Assuming timestamp is set automatically and it gets new keys...

Comment: ok ! that's a first step :D thanks!  unfortunately, since the base accepts changesets, i can't have the timestampt set automaticly, and also i have the user to set, any way to set fields to a 'const' value? e.g; select x,y,z+1, user='pipo', timestamp=somevalue ?